# CSS Flexbox height

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a chat layout. So i have 3 divs, activeUSer - top, messages middle (has to fill the space between 1 and 3), actions - bottom

Now, I've put flex-direction row. and it works fine. I needed the bottom div to grow if the input grows (if you have 2 or more lines of writing)

It worked ok untill I added display:flex to the Actions div (bottom). I needed another flex layout for input and buttons. Now it does not care for the padding i've set on the last div

Here is my codepen https://codepen.io/capraruioan/pen/XKWxrV

```
#content {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.activeUser { 
height: 66px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Messages { 
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.Actions {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
    padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.aa { //the inputbox
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by letting display default on the 3rd div and placing a div with display flex inside